# Prove that product outer measure of metric outer measures is metric

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If we have two outer measures $\mu$ on X and $\nu$ on Y, take two subsets $A\subset X, B\subset Y$ and $E=A\times B$. Then the outer measure is defined like this:
$$
\mu*\nu(E) =\inf\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i)\nu(B_i)\mid  E\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\times B_i,\ \text{$A_i$ is $\mu$-measurable, $B_i$ is $\nu$-measurable}\}.
$$
I need to show that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are both metric, then $\mu*\nu$ is metric as well. I know that $\mu*\nu$ is a regular measure, and I was thinking of using the fact that the measure is metric, if the Borel sets are measurable, but I couldn't find a solid start point of the proof and now I'm not even sure whether it's a good idea to go this way.
Could somebody at least give me a hint?

Comment: **Hint**: In $X\times Y$: 1. If $d(E,F)>0$  there are disjoint open sets $U\supseteq E$ and $W\supseteq F$.   2. The open retangles (product of two open sets) form a basis for the topology of $X\times Y$. 3. You know  $\mu*\nu$ is regular.

Comment: Okay, so at the end, I see how to prove it for separable space, but what about the general case? Would it still hold? @Ramiro, could you explain it in more details?

Comment: OK. You are right. Let me propose a better approach.  If an outer measure is defined on all subsets of a metric space then 
it is metric if and only if all Borel sets are measurable.  We can assume that $\mu$ (resp. $\nu$) is defined 
on $2^X$ (resp. $2^Y$), set of all subsets of $X$ (resp. $2^Y$). Since $\mu$ and $\nu$ are defined in $2^X$ 
and $2^Y$ respectively, we have that $\mu*\nu$ is defined on $2^{X\times Y}$.

Comment: The proof would then be: Since $\mu$ (resp. $\nu$) is a metric outer measure, we have that  
all Borel set in $X$ (resp. $Y$) are $\mu$-measurable (resp. $\nu$-measurable). Then, we know that, 
the sets in the  $\sigma$-algebra in $X\times Y$ gerenerated by the product of Borel sets in $X$ and 
Borel sets in $Y$ are $\mu*\nu$-measurable.  It  means all Borel sets in $X\times Y$ are  $\mu*\nu$-measurable. 
Now, since  $\mu*\nu$ is defined on $2^{X\times Y}$, we have that $\mu*\nu$ is a metric outer measure.